# TikZ - "Calculate" the numeric suffix of the name of a node

Tags: tikz-pgf, calculations

**Relaxing answer**

Symbol gives the answer in his comment below.

Change

```
\def\secondnode{T22}
\coordinate (M) at ($(T2#1)!.5!(\secondnode)$);
```

to

```
\coordinate (M) at ($(T2#1)!.5!(T2\the\numexpr#1+1\relax)$);
```

---

**Initial post**

In the code below, I would like to "calculate" `\secondnode` using the formulas `#1+1` to obtain `T22` wher the prefix `T2` is the same for the two nodes used in my macro.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-tab}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newcommand\commentthis[2]{
    \def\secondnode{T22}
    \coordinate (M) at ($(T2#1)!.5!(\secondnode)$); 
    \path
        (M.east) +(.75,0) node[right,blue]{#2}
    ;
}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzTabInit[espcl = 1.5]{$x$ / 1 , $-x+3$ / 1.5}{$-1$, $+1$}
    \tkzTabLine { z , + , z }
    \commentthis{1}{TEST}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\the\numexpr#1+1\relax` might help.

Comment: Relaxing is relaxing... Thanks for this ! I should have tried alone... Shame on me. :-)